# Reading the contents of a user-space page from Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, virtual-memory

I'm getting a crash as a result of a call to `kmap` and I don'nt know why. I'm hoping someone with more kernel knowledge than I can help with this. Here is the code:

```
    pgd_t *pgd = pgd_offset(vma->vm_mm, userspace_addr);
    pud_t *pud = pud_offset(pgd, userspace_addr);
    pmd_t *pmd = pmd_offset(pud, userspace_addr);
    pte_t *pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, userspace_addr);

    if (pte_present_user(*pte)) {
            void *p = NULL;
            struct page *page = pte_page(*pte);

            get_page(page);
            p = kmap(page); /* CRASH HERE??? */

            /* Read from 'p' */

            kunmap(p);
            put_page(page);
    }
```

I've isolated that the call to `kmap` is the culprit, since without it the code runs fine. All pointers are valid as far as I can tell.

I'm unsure if `pte_offset_map` should be used in conjunction with `kmap`...

The code above is run with `mm->mmap_sem` and `vma->vm_mm->page_table_lock` locked and on a `kthread` within the kernel context.

Comment: Have you done `access_ok()` on the `userspage_addr`

Comment: @Miline: I added a check and I have access to the page. I also tried swapping the `kmap()` call for `page_address()`, but NULL was returned. I'm unsure what this means.

Comment: what happens if you remove kmap()? I think pte_offset_map() does kmap_atomic() internally

Comment: @miline: The code doesn't crash with `kmap` removed. The `pte_offset_map` call does map a pointer, but it returns a `pte_t *`, which is not what I need for reading. Is there a way to resolve the `pte_t *` into a virtual memory location so that I can read it?

Comment: 1.) Post the crash log. 2.) What about page you pass to kmap? Check the page address. 3.) Why you can't use copy_from_user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. The main issue in my code was that I was passing the pointer returned from `kmap` into `kunmap`. I should have passed in the page pointer instead.

One other change would be to use `pte_offset_kernel` instead of `pte_offset_map`.